# HTML dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html

I have dropdown here and want to set the default value which is value="inventory". But not working well. Anyone know if I missing something?
I have tried selected or selected="selected" but does not working. Thank you.

```js
function item() {
  var x = document.getElementById("itemType").value;
  if (x == "P&L") {
    $("#ML").prop("checked", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- ITEM TYPE -->
<div class="k-edit-label">
  <label for="itemType">Item Type</label>
</div>
<select id="itemType" onchange="item()" style="width:60%; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: value">
  <option value="inventory" selected="selected">Inventory</option>
  <option value="P&L">P&L</option>
  <option value='assets'>Assets</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this `<option value="inventory" selected>Inventory</option>`

```html
<select id="itemType" onchange="item()" style="width:60%; margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;" data-role="dropdownlist" data-bind="value: value">
  <option value="inventory" selected>Inventory</option>
  <option value="P&L">P&L</option>
  <option value='assets'>Assets</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just remove your all `jquery` and `javascript` code and then run just html code. You can run code in my answer and check it's working fine

Comment: I think its working well here but when I tried into my code it be blank. I wonder what is it.

Comment: did you remove your javascript code  and just tried plain html code that is in my answer?

Comment: Not yet, I'm still figuring the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change the attribute selected like the below and the value to the Inventory because you are displaying the it as I capital so they are not matching this may even work sometime in chrome and Firefox sometimes but will not WORK in IE.

So change the value from "inventory" to "Inventory"

```
<option value="Inventory" selected>Inventory</option>
```

One more thing .value is not proper use . selected

```
document.getElementById("itemType").selected
```

Comment: Not working too. I think its working well here but in my code it be blank and I dont know why.

Comment: Check with . selected